# Is there a shorthand way to "require or download" for NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create code that will intelligently find a way to run itself, no questions asked, instead of complaining about missing dependencies. What I really want is something like

```
var aes256 = require_or_install('nodejs-aes256');
```

that equates to

```
var aes256 = null;
try {
  aes256 = require('nodejs-aes256');
} catch(e) {
  const exec = require('child_process').exec;
  console.log('nodejs-aes256 not found. I\'ll fix that for you.');
  exec('npm install --save nodejs-aes256');
  aes256 = require('nodejs-aes256');
}
```

Comment: You must never do that. It's not your code responsibility to install dependencies.

Comment: Would you want to create a separate program (which can probably just be an OS shell script) that you run first that checks to see if everything is installed properly and it really should only need to be run once.

Comment: That should be `package.json` together with `npm install`

Comment: Yep, I could, there's just something "nice" about scripts being smart and fighting tooth and nail to just do what they are asked to, instead of complaining.

Comment: It's not being smart, it's doing things they are not expected to. What if the target platform does not have `npm`? What if it does not have internet connection? What if it does not have write permissions to the directory it's installed?

Comment: catch(e2) {
  exec("sudo apt-get install npm");
} ?

Comment: What is `apt-get`? Not sure macosx or windows or fedora linux are aware of it. It still does not address other concerns though...

Comment: Well, better it fixes itself in 90% of the cases than 0%? Especially for personal scripts and simple one-off things that go on EC2 Ubuntu instances it's nice to be able to git clone and fire up everything with 1 command, "no questions asked".

Comment: Nope, better you use the tools designed for it: dependencies must be in `packages.json`. And they are installed **automatically** as a part of your program deployment/installation. "it's nice to be able" --- it's not. It's not nice to do what you are not supposed to.

Comment: What if your "fighting tooth and nail" actually breaks things instead of fixing them? Or "fixes" them with the wrong approach, leaving a mess behind? Also, what if your dependencies change, or require an update? You should only need to edit the `package.json`, following the *single responsibility principle*.

Comment: As jfriend said, do it in a separate program if you really want this. Write your package as usual, using only `require`, and separate tool that does everything to install your package with all ins and outs on every relevant platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is add all your dependencies to your `package.json` and add `npm install` to your start script, like this:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  (...),
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm install && node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nodejs-aes256": "*"
  }
}
```

Then, to start your program, run:

> npm start

Note that this is going to trigger npm and will increase your program start up by a few seconds. If its dependencies have already been installed, npm will not install them again.